# Is it possible to rename a SQL Server 2008 Express installation?

Tags: sql-server-2008-express

I am attempting to install (and un-install and re-install numerously) SQL Server 2008 Express. I selected install as a default instance but the setup **insists** that my installation be a named instance `localhost\sqlexpress`.

Has anyone else had this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot rename it after it is installed.  Additionally, if you are using WPI you must install with default options.  Are you using WPI or did you get your installer from the Download Center?

From MSDN:

> ### [Specifying an Instance Name other than SQLEXPRESS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd981045%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)
>
> SQL Server 2008 Express uses the default instance name of “SQLEXPRESS”.  Changing the instance name or installing additional instances requires a custom installation. You cannot change instance names once the installation is complete